# RAM and HDD usage maxes out then crashes when baking AO 4k texures using Textools in version 3.1 but not in 2.81

Tags: texture-baking

I'm a bit stumped with this one, all the settings are the same and both versions are installed in the same location (default location on an SSD). The even stranger thing is, the hard drive that maxes out isn't even linked or related to anything that's being baked.

When baking images in 1024x1024 or 2048x2048, this doesn't happen, only in 4096x4096. When baking at 4096x4096, blender becomes unresponsive and the RAM and unlinked HDD maxes out and then about 5mins in, Blender just crashes to desktop.

As mentioned in the title, I do not have this with version 2.81 when baking.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing, but apart from that I have no clue what I should be doing to sort this out. Obviously I can just bake textures in 2.81, but as you can apprecite I would much like to have just one version to use for modeling and baking.

If anyone can help with this I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

edit; I've discovered why the HHD was being used, it was related to the pagefile location. I have changed the pagefile location, but the problem persists. So still not sure why version 3.1 is causing this issue when baking

Comment: If you found something that is not related to other version you might fill a bug report